# Finite closed covering of a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

> My Attempt:

I think here I can define the diameter of $A$ as follows since it is bounded.

diam $A=\sup \{|x-y|: x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$

So, I can take each $r_k$ as diam $A$.

Am I on the right track? Or is there something else I have to consider? I appreciate your opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $S = \{\sum r_k^2 : A \text{ can be covered by } (\bar B(a_k,r_k))_{k=1}^n\}$.  You have shown that $S$ is non-empty.  Note also that all elements of $S$ are non-negative.  It now suffices to show that $S$ is closed.